# Why i dont see FB login screen after FB.logout() is called and page is refreshed?

Tags: facebook, logout

i have FB app which have access to user photos. First time, when you visit app, you are prompted to enter login and password in standard FB login popup.
We are using

```
FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', 
      status     : true,
      xfbml      : false 
    });
```

After image is selected and used in our app, `FB.logout()` is called.
Then when i refresh the page i would expect FB to ask me again for a login and password, but i am just automatically logged in without asking for login and password.
How can i achieve that `FB.logout()` will log me out properly and i will be asked to enter login and password each time ?

I tried to use `auth_type: 'reauthenticate'`

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  // Original FB.login code
}, { auth_type: 'reauthenticate' })
```

I tried to delete `fblo_APPID` cookie

Nothing helped.

Thanks

Comment: Initializing the SDK with `status: true` means it will automatically recognize the user and log them in to your app again, if they are logged in to Facebook. And `FB.logout` is only supposed to log the user out of Facebook, if they logged in to Facebook while logging in to your app. It sounds like that is what you are doing here though, so if that did not log you out of Facebook, then I’d check what the response contained in the callback function first of all.

Comment: changing status to false or true doesnt make any change. if i change it to false, it also dont ask me for login details

Comment: i tried also to remove permissions, but that leads to popup window, where can i authorize app again, but it still recognize me as previous logged user  ```FB.api(
 '/me/permissions',
 'DELETE',
 {},
 function(response) {
     // Here fb should remove the token.
     // response should be "success: true"
     FB.logout(() => {
              // Here logout.
     });
 }
);```